# Expressing a piecewise-defined function in terms of the unit step function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to express $ f(t) $ in terms of the unit step function

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
 t^2& 0\leq t<2 \\ 
1& t\geq 2
\end{cases}$$

My solution:

$$f(t) = t^2u(t) + 2u(t-2)$$

I see that when $ t \geq 2$ it is a straight line at $t=2$, so then $2u(t-2)$ would be the unit step function of that part. However, I am not quite sure about the first part when $t^2, \ 0\leq t<2 $ I know this is a parabola ranging from $(0,0)$ to $(2,4)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $f(t)=t^2 u(t) + (1-t^2) u(t-2)$, and it produces this graph:

[image]

Your original attempt makes instead this graph:

[image]

Can you see where you went wrong?

Comment: not quite sure where i went wrong there

Comment: You never removed the $t^2$ on $t\geq 2$

Comment: oh yes okay i see where i went wrong, thanks for your time ill accept the answer when the timer allows